# Make a Job on Hudson C/C++

Tags: c#, hudson

I want make a Job on Hudson. My Project are in C++. I am an absolutly beginner with Hudson. Can you gibe me an Example how i have to do it?

Thanks für your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a new **free-style software project** job.
- **Configure** that job.
- (Optional) Under **Source Code Management** section, select your **SCM** source and configure your repositories and local workspace
- Under **Build** section, select **Add build step** and select:
  **Execute Shell** if on *nix
  **Execute Windows Batch Command** if on Windows
- Write your build/make/compile command as you would from command line
- (Optional) Archive the artifacts of the build with **Archive the artifacts** under **Post-build Actions**