# Want to make a Job on Hudson C/C++

Tags: c++, c, svn, hudson, hudson-plugins

Hopefully I find here someone who has experience with Hudson and its functions.

Now . I have Hudson installed this did not reveal any problems. But now I want to create a new job and that I'm developing in C / C + +.

In addition, I am working on Subversion svn where I run on the first error. Hudson did not find my svn . He says that I need an authentication . As I learned I can at Hudson authenticate but that does not work .

Maybe one of you knows how to create a project.

The things should be done in the job of Hudson.

1. Hudson is on my computer (local ) delete my project.
2. Then Hudson to access my SVN and check out the project from there.
3. The whole is now compiling Hudson . ( The best would be a compiler for C / C + + for Visual Studio 2008 compiler ) . The compiler then creates a * . Exe file.
4. Now Hudson to start the project on the basis of the *. Exe file and run the program .
5. Last but not least is to Hudson case of an error or if it was all right, inform the persons working on the project via email.

So that would be it what I 've hoped of Hudson. Otherwise, I take the whole not much. I know that I can do all this via a batch file . But that's not my goal. I want Hudson to automate so that I can start at midnight my builds / tests daily.

Do you think that at Hudson are my requirement too high?

For your help I would be very grateful , as I am stuck for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [**"basic"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758442/make-a-job-on-hudson-c-c) Hudson job

- Create a new **free-style software project** job.
- **Configure** that job.
- (Optional) Configure triggers, such as "timer", "SCM polling", or others.
- (Optional) Under **Source Code Management** section, select your **SCM** source and configure your repositories and local workspace
- Under **Build** section, select **Add build step** and select:
  **Execute Shell** if on *nix
  ***OR***
  **Execute Windows Batch Command** if on Windows
  ***OR***
  Pick whatever **build-step plugin** you are using.
- (If using either of the "execute" build steps) Write your build/make/compile command as you would from command line.
- (If using another plugin build step) Configure the plugin options according to your requirements.
- (Optional) Archive the artifacts of the build with **Archive the artifacts** under **Post-build Actions**
- (Optional) Execute other post-build actions
- (Optional) Send out an email

Now to address your specific scenario. First things first, your question is too broad, and may get locked. Don't get discouraged if that happens, create separate question for each item individually. I cannot cover in details all these items, but I will give you an overview.

## The SCM part

Based on your previous question, **[No Credentials to try in Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22779879/no-credentials-to-try-in-hudson)**, I am now guessing that you are not providing Hudson with an HTTP URL to your SVN server, but trying to give it your local workspace location... Please do the command line check that I asked in that question.

You **need** to provide it with a proper HTTP server URL. Hudson will check out the project from the SVN URL you provided, under what is called a **Workspace**. The location of workspace can differ, based on your Hudson configuration, but it is a folder inside Hudson installation that is dedicated to the job. It can be referenced from within the job through `%WORKSPACE%` environment variable.

There are ways to use a different workspace location, but that is outside the scope of this overview. The whole SCM part is also optional, you can rely on existing file system, but this is not a good approach, and again, out of scope of this overview.

## The Build step

After Hudson checked-out/updated the **Workspace** with your SVN, comes the **building** step. Hudson can do **Execute Windows Batch Command** by default. It can also **Invoke Ant** by default. (It can also do Maven, but that is not applicable to your situation)

To do other types of builds, you need a **[Build Wrapper plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/All+Plugins+by+Topic#AllPluginsbyTopic-Buildwrappers)**. In your particular case, the **[MSBuild plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/MSBuild+Plugin)** is probably what you want. I've never used MSBuild, so cannot give you details. Again, if you have a specific question on how to use MSBuild plugin, you should probably make a separate question with specific issues.

So, using either **Execute Windows Batch Command** or **MSBuild plugin**, configure your building step.

## Running the exe???

This is very vague. You want to start the `.exe` and then what? Will it quit and you need an exit code? Do you want to see it on the screen? Again, this is very broad, and deserves a separate question (or read existing questions). If you just want to make a call to the `.exe`, you can configure a *second* **Execute Windows Batch Command** step, type there `call path\to\yourfile.exe`. But most likely you will not see that on screen. Read my answer here, **[Open Excel on Jenkins CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602951/open-excel-on-jenkins-ci)**, on details of launching an `.exe` from Hudson/Jenkins that would be visible on screen.

## Email

If you want a simple email, Hudson **Post-Build actions** has a way to send an email. For better customization options, you would want **[Email-Ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin)**. Once again, if you need details on how to use the email-ext plugin, create a new question (after searching existing questions first), as this is too much to cover in one question.

## Conclusion

Your requirements are not too high, but Hudson is not a magic tool that will do the work for you. You still need to configure every step of it. And unless you have a Maven based project (which integrate very well with Hudson), a lot of actions will need to be done through the **Execute Windows Batch Command** and scripting of your own.